# Generate a graph for the diffusion equation

Tags: python, matplotlib, pde

I have a code that represents the diffusion equation (Concentration as a function of time and space):

∂²C/∂x² - ∂C/∂t= 0

I discretized to the following form:

C[n+1,j] = C[n,j] + (dt/dx²)*(C[n,j+1] - 2*(C[n,j]) + C[n,j-1])

I am trying to generate the following graph, however I haven't had much success. Is there anyone who could help me with this? Many thanks!

[image]

The graph that I obtain:

[image]

The code that I have to reproduce the diffusion equation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dt = 0.001 # grid size for time (s)
dx = 0.05 # grid size for space (m)
x_max = 1 # in m
t_max = 1 # total time in s
C0 = 1 # concentration
 
# function to calculate concentration profiles based on a 
# finite difference approximation to the 1D diffusion 
# equation:
def diffusion(dt,dx,t_max,x_max,C0):
    # diffusion number:
    s = dt/dx**2
    x = np.arange(0,x_max+dx,dx) 
    t = np.arange(0,t_max+dt,dt)
    r = len(t)
    a = len(x)
    C = np.zeros([r,a]) # initial condition
    C[:,0] = C0 # boundary condition on left side
    C[:,-1] = 0 # boundary condition on right side
    for n in range(0,r-1): # time
        for j in range(1,a-1): # space
            C[n+1,j] = C[n,j] + s*(C[n,j-1] -
                2*C[n,j] + C[n,j+1]) 
    return x,C,r,a
# note that this can be written without the for-loop 
# in space, but it is easier to read it this way
 
x,C,r,a = diffusion(dt,dx,t_max,x_max,C0)
 
# plotting:
plt.figure()
plt.xlim([0,1])
plt.ylim([0,1])
plot_times = np.arange(0,1,0.02)
for t in plot_times:
    plt.plot(x,C[int(t/dt),:],'Gray',label='numerical')
plt.xlabel('Membrane position x',fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Concentration',fontsize=12)
```

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: This is off topic for here, but you did note that the time steps are logarithmically spaced in the plot you are trying to emulate?

Comment: yes, I did, but then I do not know how to plot them at certain values of time.